# Run seleniumtest using webdriver java for all browsers, without opening any browser

Tags: java, selenium, testing

I have a general question about selenium:

Is there a way to run selenium webdriverv2 using java, in different browsers(chrome\firefox\safari...) without opening any browser?

I read about selenium [grid](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/grid/), unfortunate in grid it open the browsers/machines.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to open a browser, then Selenium isnt for you. If you want headless testing my suggestion would be to look into [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/).

Comment: Thanx!!, Yes this is an some way, i find another, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Selenium for 6 month, but when I used it, it was necessary to open the browser and I think still being like that today.

Comment: Yes i can, see my answer for the question.